# Buttons pushed outside the view

Tags: android, view

I have a view with 6 buttons.Buttons are side by side and underneath each other (two rows) The result of my button.xml is normal when I use preview in Android Studio. But when build with emulator all the buttons are pushed upwards. Half of the buttons are pushed outside the view. Why is a preview results not the same as emulator? How can I fix this? Below my code:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background">

    <Button
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btnScan"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/btnScan5"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/btnScan5"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/btnScan3"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:drawableTop="@drawable/paper"
        android:onClick="buttonOnClick"
        android:text="Button 1"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"></Button>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnScan1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="60dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:drawableTop="@drawable/exam"
        android:onClick="buttonOnClick"
        android:text="Button 2"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:layout_below="@+id/btnScan4"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"></Button>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnScan2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/btnScan4"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/btnScan4"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="70dp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:drawableTop="@drawable/pen"
        android:onClick="buttonOnClick"
        android:text="Button 3"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"></Button>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnScan3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:drawableTop="@drawable/bulletedlist"
        android:onClick="buttonOnClick"
        android:text="Button 4"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/btnScan1"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/btnScan1"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/btnScan2"></Button>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnScan4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:drawableTop="@drawable/curriculumpng"
        android:onClick="buttonOnClick"
        android:text="Button 5"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/btnScan1"></Button>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnScan5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/btnScan1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/btnScan1"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:drawableTop="@drawable/globearth"
        android:onClick="buttonOnClick"
        android:text="Button 6"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"></Button>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Post an image of your problem, screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

I Suggest you to use Linear layout inside your Frame layout. Just try the below code.

```
   <LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <LinearLayout
        android:weightSum="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <Button
            android:text="Button 1"
            android:id="@+id/button_one"
            android:layout_weight="0.33"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <Button
            android:text="Button 2"
            android:id="@+id/button_two"
            android:layout_weight="0.33"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <Button
            android:text="Button 3"
            android:id="@+id/button_three"
            android:layout_weight="0.33"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:weightSum="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <Button
            android:text="Button 4"
            android:id="@+id/button_four"
            android:layout_weight="0.33"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <Button
            android:text="Button 5"
            android:id="@+id/button_five"
            android:layout_weight="0.33"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <Button
            android:text="Button 6"
            android:id="@+id/button_six"
            android:layout_weight="0.33"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```